# The pipeline failed to work in complicated shell commands within heredoc which will pass to su for execute

Tags: shell

Firstly, I created a directory named test with two files in it:

```
$ find ./test -type f
./test/111
./test/222
```

Then I put the following code in a script to do the testing:

```
test-su.bash
-----------
#!/usr/bin/env bash

topdir=$(
cd -P -- "$(dirname -- "$0")" &&
pwd -P
)

cd $topdir

su -- root -p -c 'exec 0<&3 3<&- && "$SHELL" ${1+"$@"}' \
  su 3<<EOF
find ./test -type f |
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "the file under test dir is: $line"
done
EOF
-----------
```

Then I put the above script in the parent directory of test directory and 
run it:

```
$ bash test-su.bash 
Password: 
the file under test dir is: 
the file under test dir is: 
^C
$
```

As you can see, in the latter case, the `read' command in the while loop 
failed to obtain the output of find.

Any hints for this issue?

Regards